# How to find original mint transactions for crypto punks?

Tags: etherscan, nft, mint

looking at etherscan https://etherscan.io/token/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb
im unclear how to identify original mint transactions. Usually filtering from Null address works but looking at the transactions history it seems the earliest buy punks methods calls were from non null addresses.

Answer (score 1):

There's an earlier version of CryptoPunks token -

https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0x6ba6f2207e343923ba692e5cae646fb0f566db8d&p=304

It was fully minted upon deployment and people who wanted to get one just called `getPunk(uint256 punkIndex)`.

Comment: thanks for linking v1 contract. so the entire collection was minted at the following transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9fef127966d59d440c70f28c8e6f1eac3af0d91f94384e207deb3c98ff9c3088 ?

additionally, the getPunk calls From addresses are the ones that Minted?

Comment: is there an easy way to filter transactions of getPunk method calls? since it seems all transactions From address is fixed to  Cryptopunks: Old Token

Comment: @jasan The function `getPunk` generates an event `Assign(address indexed to, uint256 punkIndex)`.